# Drag an element and droppable in to all elements with same class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating an application in jQuery. I want to drag an element and drop that element in to some elements with same class at a time using jQuery. I can drag an element with id draggable in to element with class droppable2, ie. only one element. I want to drop all elements with class `droppable2`.
Can anybody give any solution for these  issue?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            #draggable {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                padding: 0.5em;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
            }
            .droppable2 {
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                padding: 0.5em;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px;
                border:solid #000099;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#draggable").draggable();
                $("#drop").droppable({
                    var contenthtml = $(this).html();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="draggable">
            <p>Drag me to my target</p>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable2" id="drop">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable2">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>   
        <div class="droppable2">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: look into the accept: function , maybe this will work ` $(".droppable2").droppable({
     accept:".droppable2",
     accept:"#draggable",
     drop: function( event, ui ) {     
       var contenthtml = $(this).html();
                    
     
     }`

Comment: ps, your #drop doesn't exist in the droppable()

Comment: added your code,but it is not working